# yum " Segmentation fault" in centos

Tags: centos, yum

While using yum commands in a centos server(2.6.18-194.el5PAE #1), it throws 'Segmentation fault'.

> [root@server2 ~]# yum check-update
>
> Loaded plugins: fastestmirror Loading
> mirror speeds from cached hostfile
>
> Segmentation fault
>
> [root@server2 ~]# yum installlve-devel cmake
>
> Loaded plugins:
> fastestmirror Loading mirror speeds
> from cached hostfile Segmentation fault
>
> [root@server2 ~]# yum update
>
> Loaded plugins: fastestmirror Loading
>
> mirror speeds from cached hostfile
>
> Segmentation fault

How can I solve this?

Comment: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/StackTraces

Comment: Here is the result:

> [root@server2 ~]# yum clean all 

> Loadedplugins: fastestmirror Cleaning up
> Everything Cleaning up list of fastest
> mirrors
 
> 
> [root@server52 ~]# yum -v check-update
 
> Loading "fastestmirror" plugin Config
> time: 0.036 Yum Version: 3.2.22
> Setting up Package Sacks Determining
> fastest mirrors cloudlinux-base       
> cloudlinux-base/primary               
> Segmentation fault

Comment: That looks like an issue with your repo files or with the data being returned when you connect to one of them.  It might be the cloudlinux-base repo, or it might be the next one.  To troubleshoot, I'd disable all but one repo, and see if you can get it to work.  Try "yum check-updates --disablerepo=cloudlinux-base" and also see http://rajaseelan.com/2009/07/24/temporarily-disable-a-yum-repository/ for more information

Comment: Are you sure you're not running out of memory?
I've had a similar problem caused by mysqld daemon that were occupating all the available memory.
Run top command and see how much free memory you have, maybe that's the cause of your problem.

Answer (score 5):

The issue was with zlib upgrade from source which is a problem affect all RHEL/CentOS/CL installations:

http://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=4702&nbn=1

I have removed source zlib

> /usr/local/lib/libz.so.1.2.5

and Changed the links

> /usr/local/lib/libz.so ->
>   libz.so.1.2.5 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root
>   13 Sep 24  2010
>   /usr/local/lib/libz.so.1 ->
>   libz.so.1.2.5

to point to libz.so.1.2.3. This has fixed the issue.

Comment: This saved me a lot of heart-ache. Building zlib 1.2.6 on Fedora 12 64-bit causes yum to segfault, fix is to just not do this.

Answer (score 4):

You can try repairing your rpm db and re-doing the cache

```
rm -rf /var/lib/rpm/__db.*
rpm --rebuilddb
yum clean all
yum makecache
```

Comment: Both `yum` and `rpm` were giving my "`bus error"`s on Centos 7.3, this fixed 'em.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I do when yum starts behaving strangely is

```
# yum clean all
```

It's hard to say from the info you've given here, but it seems a good guess that your cache and mirror files are corrupt.  The above command will help fix that.  If it doesn't work, then post the output of

```
# yum -v check-update
```

Comment: Now, try running "yum check-update" again, and see if it still segfaults.

Comment: Still the same result ...

Comment: see my other comment.  It's likely an issue with your repo or with the data returned by one of them.

Answer (score 0):

If you're still seeing problems, replace the yum binary from a copy from another machine.

Comment: yum is a set of Python scripts.

Answer (score 0):

At this point I'd try testing the memory.

Run [memtest](http://www.memtest.org), best to leave it running for the night.

Answer (score 0):

I have also seen this problem and was able to clear it by removing .repo files (which happened to reference non-existent repositories) from /etc/yum.repos.d/