# CentOS 5.7 Yum Segmentation fault (core dumped) error

Tags: centos5, yum, segmentation-fault

My system Info: OS :CentOS release 5.7 (Final)

```
Apache 2.2.3 Server Running
DirectAdmin 1.40.1  Running
Exim 4.76           Running
MySQL 5.1.57        Running
Named 9.3.6         Running
ProFTPd 1.3.3c      Running
sshd                Running
dovecot 2.0.16      Running
Php 5.2.17          Installed

Total Memory        8052740 kB
Free Memory         3680156 kB
Total Swap Memory   25164468 kB
Free Swap Memory    25164468 kB
```

While i was trying to install php-imap by doing

```
 yum install php-imap
```

i got following error.

```
[root@www mailer]#  yum install php-imap
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Determining fastest mirrors
 * base: mirrors.supportex.net
 * extras: mirrors.supportex.net
 * rpmforge: mirror.nl.leaseweb.net
 * updates: centos.mirror.transip.nl
base                                                     | 1.1 kB     00:00
base/primary                                             | 1.2 MB     00:00
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

i tried doing

```
[root@www mailer]#  yum search php-imap
```

and got this error.

```
[root@www mailer]#  yum search php-imap
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.supportex.net
 * extras: mirrors.supportex.net
 * rpmforge: mirror.nl.leaseweb.net
 * updates: centos.mirror.transip.nl
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

i even tried

```
[root@www mailer]# yum clean all
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Cleaning up Everything
Cleaning up list of fastest mirrors
```

and did this and got same error

```
[root@www mailer]# yum check-update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Determining fastest mirrors
 * base: mirrors.supportex.net
 * extras: mirrors.supportex.net
 * rpmforge: mirror.nl.leaseweb.net
 * updates: centos.mirror.triple-it.nl
base                                                     | 1.1 kB     00:00
base/primary                                             | 1.2 MB     00:00
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

then i tried

```
rm -rf /var/lib/rpm/__db.*
rpm --rebuilddb
yum clean all
yum makecache
```

and got this

```
[root@www mailer]# rm -rf /var/lib/rpm/__db.*
[root@www mailer]# rm -rf /var/lib/rpm/__db.*
[root@www mailer]# rpm --rebuilddb
[root@www mailer]# yum clean all
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Cleaning up Everything
Cleaning up list of fastest mirrors
[root@www mailer]# yum makecache
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Determining fastest mirrors
 * base: mirrors.supportex.net
 * extras: mirrors.supportex.net
 * rpmforge: mirror.nl.leaseweb.net
 * updates: centos.mirror.triple-it.nl
base                                                     | 1.1 kB     00:00
base/filelists                                           | 3.6 MB     00:00
base/other                                               |  13 MB     00:01
base/group                                               | 1.1 MB     00:00
base/primary                                             | 1.2 MB     00:00
dag                                                      | 1.9 kB     00:00
dag/filelists_db                                         | 6.1 MB     00:04
dag/other_db                                             | 1.5 MB     00:01
dag/primary_db                                           | 7.0 MB     00:04
extras                                                   | 2.1 kB     00:00
extras/filelists_db                                      | 241 kB     00:00
extras/other_db                                          | 406 kB     00:00
extras/group                                             | 9.7 kB     00:00
extras/primary_db                                        | 188 kB     00:00
rpmforge                                                 | 1.9 kB     00:00
rpmforge/filelists_db                                    | 6.1 MB     00:00
rpmforge/other_db                                        | 1.5 MB     00:00
rpmforge/primary_db                                      | 7.0 MB     00:00
updates                                                  | 1.9 kB     00:00
updates/filelists_db                                     | 1.9 MB     00:00
updates/other_db                                         | 8.3 MB     00:00
updates/primary_db                                       | 383 kB     00:00
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

how can i fix this error ?
Thanks for your time.

update:
i tried doing

```
strace -f yum make cache
```

and it gave me very long output, here are last few lines.

```
futex(0x2ba19218a500, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
stat("/var/cache/yum/base/primary.xml.gz", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1303494, ...}) = 0
stat("/var/cache/yum/base/primary.xml.gz", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1303494, ...}) = 0
stat("/var/cache/yum/base/primary.xml.gz", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1303494, ...}) = 0
open("/var/cache/yum/base/primary.xml.gz", O_RDONLY) = 10
lseek(10, 0, SEEK_CUR)                  = 0
read(10, "\37\213\10\10\0\0\0\0\2\377/home/buildcentos/CENTOS/5.9/en/x86_64/.repodata/primary.xml\0\354\275Y\227\333F\2260\370\316_\201\243\207ii,0\21\10\254\32\227\347\310\222,g\227$g;\345\262\276\247<\1 \300\204\23$X\0\230\213\36\346\267\317\275\21\0\t0\261\4\310\314\224\252\272\272\313\266D\304vc\271\373\362\343\377{\273L\265k\236\27I\266\372\333327\236i|\25fQ\262Z\374\355\331\37\237\177\321\275g\377\357O\263\37\227\274d\21+\231\6\315W\305\337\236]\226\345\372\325\311I\232\2546\267\363hs\305\347<\332\234\324\255N\302l\271\314V\317d\353W\371z9\332\3\332<\323\326,\274b\v\16\343S\307\"\317`\336\352\27\255\274[\363\277=\303F?\375\270bK\376S\301\305H\372:K\223\360\356\307\23\361\343\217,\17/\177Ze\370\237\37O\304_~\254`\323\370:\v/\377\366\f\340\203_\376\366\314\234[s\347\231\226\363\24&\243\336\234\247\366\263\223\237~\f/yxUl\226\325\204\305%\203U]-\222\350o\317\376\317\273\363g?E!\261\35\213\307\226\37:!\245Q\354\370\314%\0063\31\267)\367Il\221(t\235\350\307\223z\244\237~\204\177-Y~\367\323\371\273\17\270dM.Y\v\263U\234,69+ay?\236\324\255~\214x\21\346\311\32\177\335v\371\235\307<\207s\341\332\231\354\254k\313,\332\244,\237\377x\322\354PoX\16\260l\362\364\247j\327\v\350\35\313y\347E\266\311C\36g\371\202\317W\274\374\361\4\333\375X&K\256\305I\n@\23j\273\256cZ\226\365L\v6I\32U?\231\236\341\212M*\222\257\274>\253"..., 8192) = 8192
--- SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault) @ 0 (0) ---
+++ killed by SIGSEGV (core dumped) +++
```

update:

```
[root@www ~]# tail /var/log/messages

www kernel: yum[4089]: segfault at 0000003900000000 rip 00000039cfc79e0a rsp 00007fff280dcaf8 error 4
```

**Issue Solved 
UPDATE**

as suggested by 0x534B41

i removed all zlib from

```
/usr/lib
/usr/local/lib
```

and installed

```
zlib 1.2.3

reference : 
http://www.doxer.org/learn-linux/resolved-yum-returned-segmentation-fault-error-on-centos/
http://serverfault.com/questions/256385/yum-segmentation-fault-in-centos

http://petio.org/tools/zlib.html
http://code.google.com/p/google-desktop-for-linux-mirror/downloads/detail?name=zlib-1.2.3.tar.gz&can=2&q=
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Did you have filesystem corruption recently? Running `strace -f yum make cache` may help you to understand where the problem lies.

Comment: no, never had filesystem corruption, just tried the command strace -f yum make cache and it gave very long output.

Comment: This looks like the zlib compatibility issue. Did you install zlib from sources or maybe from a binary package not provided by centos? Take a look at http://www.doxer.org/learn-linux/resolved-yum-returned-segmentation-fault-error-on-centos/ and http://serverfault.com/questions/256385/yum-segmentation-fault-in-centos .

Comment: i tried those methods and still dont work, i have updated question with issues.

Comment: thanks 0x534B41 , issue was in zlib only, fixed issue. and now yum runs perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Issue Solved UPDATE**

as suggested by **0x534B41**

i removed all zlib from

```
/usr/lib
/usr/local/lib
```

and installed

```
zlib 1.2.3
```

reference :

```
http://www.doxer.org/learn-linux/resolved-yum-returned-segmentation-fault-error-on-centos/
http://serverfault.com/questions/256385/yum-segmentation-fault-in-centos

http://petio.org/tools/zlib.html
http://code.google.com/p/google-desktop-for-linux-mirror/downloads/detail?name=zlib-1.2.3.tar.gz&can=2&q=
```

Comment: Saved my day!!!