# Segmentation fault when execute yum or rpm any command

Tags: linux, mysql, yum, httpd, rpm

I am facing some issues on centos-7 when I execute `yum install`, `yum upgrade`, `yum installed list`, `yum search`, `yum list installed`, `rpm` then getting an error `Segmentation fault`.

system Logs:-

```
segfault at 6d7072 ip 00007f52f5f98092 sp 00007fff6f504408 error 4 in librpmio.so.3.2.2[7f52f5f85000+28000]

yum[9403]: segfault at 1 ip 0000000000000001 sp 00007fff85873ca0 error 14 in python2.7[400000+1000]
```

also not able to start any service like MySQL or httpd etc.

Can you please help me or advise for the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you built any packages from source, or are all your packages downloaded from appropriate CentOS repositories? ([See this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/256385/yum-segmentation-fault-in-centos?rq=1)). Which yum is in your path?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Recently I have not installed anything on the server but I was worked before but right now I can not able to execute any commands on the server like yum or rpm and also not able to start MySQL and some other service.


Right yum path is : /usr/bin/yum 

if need any more details then please let me know.
thanks.